# copy excel data by one digit

Tags: excel, excel-formula

if i put cell value in  A1 = 10 as integer 
then i keep in mind that its number 10 and a value for next cells 
i want that if A1=10, Then i want character A in next 10 cells (a2:a11)
or if i put A1=24,then from (A2:A26) i want same character "A" 
and its changed by number itselft without any vba command button 
can any one help ?
please?

Comment: unclear what you want. Do you have any sample data to show? What about any formulas you have tried?

Comment: Something like `=IF($A$1-ROW(A1)+1>0,"A","")` and drag down really far.

Comment: @urdearboy  iif I put 5 then I want automatically drag in 5 columns as "A", beacuse i have lost of lists in sheet i dont want to drag one by one

Answer (score 1):

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"",A1<>0),LEFT("A" & SEQUENCE(A1),1),"")
```

This is for Excel 365.  *(It will spill down as far as needed without manual copying.)*

**EDIT#1:**

Without EXCEL 365, use:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)<$A$1+1,"A","")
```

and copy downward manually.

**EDIT#2:**

to get the values to go *across*, pick a cell and enter:

```
=IF(COLUMNS($A:A)<$A$1+1,"A","")
```

and copy across.

Comment: Nice use of `LEFT` here to "piggy back" on `SEQUENCE`'s spill... cute.

Comment: @BigBen  ................................thanks......................................

Comment: @adityaShrivastava  See my **EDIT**

Comment: if i put 5 A A A A A  OR 7  A A A  A A A A In horizontallY. cells increases counts by number .

Comment: @Gary'sStudent  please see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1efmOb-iAmvfF_IZor6Kd1ygBWzOTvhdQG16cq_16CUA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @adityaShrivastava  I get ***Access Denied***

Comment: @Gary'sStudent student https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1efmOb-iAmvfF_IZor6Kd1ygBWzOTvhdQG16cq_16CUA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @adityaShrivastava  See my **EDIT#2**